# Question about "as anything"

Tags: meaning-in-context, as

> Potions are delicate mixtures. They're just as liable to go off in your face **as anything**.

Source: Diablo II, Lysander the potion seller

What does “as anything” mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally, "as anything" makes a comparison to everything else.  It means that you can't find anything else that's more likely to go off in your face.  This indicates a high degree of likelihood.

In other words, nothing is more likely to explode in your face, which is likely to injure you.  According to this potion seller, potions are very likely to explode in your face, so be careful!

Answer (score 2):

I read that differently from snailboat, and would add elided words to get: "They're just as liable to go off in your face as [to do] anything [else]." I.e., the potion has *equal* odds of working as it has of exploding in your face. (Or worse, if you include *failure* in that "anything else" -- their chance of exploding in your face is as great as the chances of them simply failing AND the chances of their working, combined!)

Nevertheless, I agree with snailboat: these are not safe potions! (My Wizard will take five, please.)